# RDS Connection String in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, connection-string, rds, xeround

I'm frantically beginning the move from Xeround to Amazon RDS. I've been unable to connect to RDS via PHP. I've tried a number of variations of the following:

```
$connection = @mysql_connect('host:port','uname','password')
```

Nothing seems to go through. I'm using the same port value as I had used previously with Xeround, so that's not the issue. I'm certain the host is the endpoint and the username and password are correct. I've tried using the same parameters in C# and the MySQL workbench, but to no avail. What should I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: what error did you get? Have you tried with `mysql_error()` to know the exact error?

Comment: Have you tried using the default port, instead of specifying `:port`? I've used RDS from PHP and never needed to specify the port.

Comment: Are your security groups set up correctly? Good luck with the frantic migration :(

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. I needed to edit the security group and add a CIDR exception for the current IP address. The connection string I initially posted was correct.

Thanks!